# Each HTML div Requires item

Tags: jquery, match, each

HTML:

```
<div><input type="text" name="">{name}</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="{demo}" value="{yes}"></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="{demo}" value="{no}"></div>
```

JS:

```
$.each($('div'), function (k, v) {
    var s = $(v).html();
    console.log(s.match(/{(.*)}/gi));
});
```

I am trying to parse out all of the items wrapped in `{`curly braces`}`.

I expect to see the following result:

`['{name}', '{demo}', '{yes}', '{no}']`

But when I run the code, I get this instead:

`['{name}', '{demo} value="{yes}', '{demo} value="{no}']`

Comment: please add some more detail!!!

Comment: the code result 
`> {name}`
`> {demo} value="{yes}`
`> {demo} value="{no}`
but need result
`> {name}`
`> {demo}`
`> {yes}`
`> {no}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/{(.*)}/gi`

In your regular expression, the `*` quantifier is "greedy" by default. This means it will try to capture as much as possible. Because of that, you're getting broader matches than you're expecting.

One solution is to make your `*` operator "lazy" by adding a `?`:

`/{(.*?)}/gi`

A better solution would be to use a character class that matches all characters that are not `}` instead of matching any character with `.`:

`/{([^}]*)}/gi`

Comment: search and and change  value and html for whats need

Comment: $(this).html is true but value not changing

Comment: nderscore How can I reach you ?

Comment: @Locked Please send carrier pidgeon. But, honestly I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: nderscore we need pro "f-e"

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><input type="text" name="">{name}</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="{demo}" value="{yes}"></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="{demo}" value="{no}"></div>

var t = ["{name}":"Name","{yes}":Yes,"{no}":"No i didnt"]
$.each($('div'),function(k,v){
 var var s = $(v).html();
 var d = s.match(/{([^}]*)}/gi); 
 $(v).html(t[d]);
});
```

value not change